# "WebFrame has been modified too many times, aborting " error coming in xcode and ios 10.3

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ios10.3

i am working on a ionic project having following config:
cordova : 6.3.1
node : 6.10.3
ionic : 2.1.4
mac os sierra
x code 8.3.2

while running the project on the simulator of iPhone 6s 10.3 version i am getting the below mentioned error in x code output and app gets hanged on the splashScreen and login page is taking too long to come , and the buttons on the pages are responding very slow , i am not having any knowledge of objective c so unable to get the meaning of the error .

Any help is appreciated.

xcode output error:

Operation DDWebKitOperation: 0x6100000e9a00: container WebFrame: 0x610000001500 has been modified too many times, aborting

Comment: I have the same error on an angular/ionic build on ios.  After splash screen I have a blank screen and this error appeared.

Comment: still struggling for solution of this , i have made the build using xcode version 7.x.x and its absolutely working fine with 10.3.3 , not able to understand what is the problem .

Answer (score 1):

I've eliminated this error.  I'm not sure if what I did will help you but I'll let you know just in case.  What I've been doing is building my app in AngularJS 1.  Then when I have a distribution ready I'm putting that in the www of the ionic project, then running the builds for ios and android.  I'm NOT using any part of ionic other than using it to build so I started thinking perhaps I would take ionic out of the equation.

I updated to the latest version of xcode, then I used straight cordova to do the builds.  Splash screen appears, fades, then app loads and works as it should.  Voila.  App now released on app store.

This also helped me resolve a different issue with the InAppBrowser plugin not working.  On ios I had outgoing links which were opening the in app browser, then the user couldn't go back to the app because there was no back button.

Comment: Can you expand a bit on this fix you arrived it? Having the exact same issue, but I was already doing a build with cordova via ```cordova build ios```,  is that what you ended up doing?

Comment: Yes I went pure cordova and eliminated anything ionic since I was not using it. Make sure you are including cordova.js and all your cordova plugins are updated.